# CLion does not see wxwidgets partially but compiles project

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, clion

I use Artix linux on OpenRC, I have installed wxwidgets with `wxgtk3-dev` package (version 3.1.5) from AUR and I wanted to work with that library in CLion. CLion sees it and I'm able to include anything from wx/ dir.

I have copied a [hello world example](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html) from wxwidgets website and pasted it into my cpp source file and then CLion showed me a bunch of `undeclired identifier` errors (though some 'identifiers' like `wxFrame` are not 'undeclared'). But I'm able to build and run project and it works fine.
What's wrong with CLion and what can I do to fix this?

I've seen some guides but most of them tell about Windows and also they tell how to compile project that is not the problem in my case - it's compiling but CLion tells me that it won't compile (and still builds and runs it).

Here's also my `CMakeLists.txt` if needed: https://pastebin.com/58NwS4AP

Comment: building process in C++ consists of 2 stages - compiling and linking. It looks like the first one succeeded, but second one failed. You need to tell the linker where to find the appropriate wx libraries and which libraries to use. Also, you program is not running - since it failed to build. You are seriously mistaken here.

Comment: It's not failing to build - it compiles and runs (I can change some string constants in code and they will change in running program)

Comment: And I also see CMake logs every time and there are not any errors or warnings

Comment: do you mean the editor shows that error/warning? You need to rebuild the index or whatever it is called in `CLion`. If you try to use `std::string` for example - does it give you any error as well? Or std::thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved my problem. As you can see in my `CMakeLists.txt` it uses C++14. It seems that CLion can not properly handle some code from example with C++14 although it's not a problem for `cmake` and `make` to build it. I just switched to C++11:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

and now everything works!